# I am getting comma seperated IDs and I have to pass that in where clause inside Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I am passing comma separated string in proc execution

```
create replace proc(trasactionID in varchar2,
user_data out refcursor,
succdata out varchar2,
errodata out varchar2)

begin
open user_data for 
select name,id from table a where id in(trasactionID);
end;
/
```

Comment: how are you determining the list of values? you know you can use a subquery, yes? select blah from table where a in (select x from table where...)

Comment: I will receiving comma seperated values from java eg: proc('1,2,3,4,5,9',out_ref,out_succ,out_error);

Comment: also as values are huge so I changes my first parameter to blob. Can we achive this without using table?

Comment: `select name,id from tablea where id in(select regexp_substr(transactionID, '[^,]+', 1, level) from dual connect by level <= regexp_count(transactionID, ',')+1)`

Comment: exactly how does this comma delimited list arrive to be passed as an input parm?  Can you arrange to have it delivered as a file - and instead of comma-delimited, each entry a record in the file?  If so, you could make that file an external table to be accessed in a sub-query.

Comment: if it's 'huge' you should know your IN list is limited by 1,000 values, after that you'll HAVE to use a subquery

Comment: but i have input parameter of clob datatype and table column is number type. Also i cannot create table outside the proc.

Comment: Can we solve this issue with array? Although I want single resultset

Comment: Does this help? [How to split comma separated string and pass to IN clause of select statement](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement)

Comment: Regexp_substr does not work inside proc. It throws error that subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: what is the exact error you got (ora-....)? the suggestion above should not return such error as 'single row subquery returns more than one row'. Edit the question to show us how you rewrote it.

Comment: i am getting ORA-00604 and ORA-00932 due to parameter as CLOB type. please help me in this i am really stuck

Comment: Can we use array for this comma seperated input and pass it at once in my select ref_cursor.? plz help